# How to build a model in MXNet using matrices and matrix operations explicitly?

Tags: mxnet

I can create a model using the pre-build high-level functions like `FullyConnected`. For example:

```
X = mx.sym.Variable('data')
P  = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data = X, name = 'fc1', num_hidden = 2)
```

In this way I get a symbolic variable `P` that is dependent on the symbolic variable `X`. In other words, I have computational graph that can be used to define a model and execute such operations as `fit` and `predict`.

Now, I would like to express `P` through `X` in a different way. In more detail, instead of using the high-level functionality (like `FullyConnected`), I would like to specify relations between `P` and `X` "explicitly", using low-level tensor operations (like matrix multiplication) and symbolic variables representing model parameters (lake weight matrix).

For example to achieve the same as above, I have tried the followig:

```
W = mx.sym.Variable('W')
B = mx.sym.Variable('B')
P = mx.sym.broadcast_plus(mx.sym.dot(X, W), B)
```

However, `P` obtained this way is not equivalent to `P` obtained earlier. I cannot use it the same way. In particular, as far as I understand, MXNet is complaining that `W` and `B` do not have values (which makes sense).

I have also tried to declare `W` and `B` in another way (so that they do have values):

```
w = np.array([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
b = np.array([7.0, 8.0])

W = mx.nd.array(w)
B = mx.nd.array(b)
```

It does not work as well. I guess that MXNet complains because it expects a symbolic variable but it gets nd-arrays instead.

So, my question is how to build a model using low-level tensor operations (like matrix multiplication) and explicit objects representing model parameters (like weight matrices).

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at Gluon API. For example here is a guide for building MLP from scratch, including allocating the parameters:

```
#######################
#  Allocate parameters for the first hidden layer
#######################
W1 = nd.random_normal(shape=(num_inputs, num_hidden), scale=weight_scale, ctx=model_ctx)
b1 = nd.random_normal(shape=num_hidden, scale=weight_scale, ctx=model_ctx)

params = [W1, b1, ...]
```

Attaching them to the automatic gradient

```
for param in params:
    param.attach_grad()
```

Define the model:

```
def net(X):
    #######################
    #  Compute the first hidden layer
    #######################
    h1_linear = nd.dot(X, W1) + b1
    ...
```

and execute it

```
epochs = 10
learning_rate = .001
smoothing_constant = .01

for e in range(epochs):
    ...
    for i, (data, label) in enumerate(train_data):
        data = data.as_in_context(model_ctx).reshape((-1, 784))
        label = label.as_in_context(model_ctx)
        ...
        with autograd.record():
            output = net(data)
            loss = softmax_cross_entropy(output, label_one_hot)
        loss.backward()
        SGD(params, learning_rate)
```

You can see the full example in the straight dope:

http://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter03_deep-neural-networks/mlp-scratch.html